# Reading all files that start with a certain string in a directory

Tags: python, file, reference, directory

Say I have a directory.

- In this directory there are single files as well as folders.
- Some of those folders could also have subfolders, etc.
- What I am trying to do is find all of the files in this directory that start with "Incidences" and read each csv into a pandas data frame.
- I am able to loop through all the files and get the names, but cannot read them into data frames.
- I am getting the error that "___.csv" does not exist, as it might not be directly in the directory, but rather in a folder in another folder in that directory.

I have been trying the attached code.

```
inc_files2 = []
pop_files2 = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        if f.startswith('Incidence'):
            inc_files2.append(f)
        elif f.startswith('Population Count'):
            pop_files2.append(f)
for file in inc_files2:
    inc_frames2 = map(pd.read_csv, inc_files2)
for file in pop_files2:
    pop_frames2 = map(pd.read_csv, pop_files2)
```

Comment: You're not iterating through `dirs` to find files in sub-folders.  Did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding only file name to the lists, not their path. You can use something like this to add paths instead:

```
inc_files2.append(os.path.join(root, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path from the root directory where you are

Answer (score 0):

Append the entire pathname, not just the bare filename, to `inc_files2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.path.abspath(f)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to read the full path of a file.

You can make use of this by making the following changes to your code.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        f_abs = os.path.abspath(f)
        if f.startswith('Incidence'):
            inc_files2.append(f_abs)
        elif f.startswith('Population Count'):
            pop_files2.append(f_abs)
```